# Wine label matching

Tags: android, image, match

I'm working on an application which works like that:

You take a photo of the label of a bottle of wine, and the app scan your picture, and if it is similar to a template stored in the drawable folder, you receive a pop-up which contains the name and other characteristics of your wine. (everything offline)

I've searched on Github and on Google, but I've found few projects or hints.
Can you link me some working project or help me with the code?
Because I'm not able to make the comparison code.

Comment: What you need is an OCR (Optical Character Recognition). OpenCV has OCR capabilities. Anyway, asking us to recommend you resources is off-topic for this site.

Answer (score 0):

Well it is not that simple to take a photo and match a template from the drawable folder. Because images simply cannot be compared using conventional methods.
There is a wide research area called **'Computer Vision'**  dedicated only for this. But if you still want to achieve the outcome you are expecting. I suggest you to do some research on classification problem in computer vision. And to get started . You can try [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/examples/android) android implementation of tensorflow (Google's neural network library). And tweak it as required

Answer (score 0):

You can estimate the SIFT (Scale Invariant Feature Transform) features of the label, and match it with candidate images. Search for "OpenCV SIFT example" and you will get working c++/python code to do this.

Comment: I've tried with Opencv and I've posted a question with a 50% working code.
I can compare 2 images but I don't have the right matching percentage.
that's my question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38696938/android-opencv-template-matching-with-camera-picture